# Display multiple json objects from a nested json to a cell data in Vuetable

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm currently using [Vuetable-2](https://github.com/ratiw/vuetable-2) to display data from my server.

Is there a way to display multiple json objects from a nested json to a a cell data in Vuetable?

**Response payload from server:**
[image]

**Current Table Format:**
[image]

**Expected result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

have you try this on your vue script for "fields":

```
fields:['SubCategories[0].subCategoryName']
```